# Convergence and continuity

Tags: continuity

${f_n}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on every interval $[a,b]$. Prove $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that it must be the case that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. But how can this be extended to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What kind of convergence does $f_n \to f$ refer to? Because your proposition is wrong for *pointwise* convergence... Since you mention an interval, I'm assuming the $f_n$ are supposed to converge uniformly on every finite interval, right?

Comment: Yes, $f_n -> f$ uniformly

Comment: Can you add that condition to the question?

Comment: The math nerd answer: Continuity is defined locally, so being continuous on any $[a,b]$ means continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x \in [x-1, x+1]$ and $f$ is continuous on this interval, hence at $x$.

Comment: And x-1, x+1 can be chosen arbitrarily? This would guarantee that the property holds for any interval?

Comment: I'm reading your hypotheses to be that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on all intervals $[a,b]$. In particular, on the one I picked.

Comment: This would guarantee convergence on R because R is composed of closed intervals like this one?

Comment: since $x$ is arbitrary it will be continuous on the union of all such intervals, which is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What I have shown is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ for all points $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is exactly what it means for a function to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.